# Amazon S3 Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer on Mobile Apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon uses this example to create a policy for restricting domain access:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is great and works perfectly fine for web apps, but there is no clarification on how this behaves in mobile apps. I'd like to be able to have these images display in our mobile apps but I'm not sure how this would need to work.

Does anyone have any experience here or can point me in the right direction? I haven't been successful in searching the docs and doing some google searches. I'll continue looking as well.

Comment: What makes you think this would be handled differently for mobile apps? A mobile app is just another HTTP client in this regard. The origin or Referer will be set for the same reasons as any browser.

Answer (score 4):

Mobile apps would have to set the HTTP `referer` header in the requests they make for anything they attempt to load from that bucket.

Comment: Great but how does it verify that the domain belongs to me. Isn't this easily spoofable?

Comment: There is no domain ownership verification. Yes it is easily spoofable. If you thought the `referer` restriction in your S3 bucket was very secure you were mistaken. If you want something better you probably need to be generating pre-signed URLs on the server side

Comment: So what's the point of even using the HTTP referrer policy then?

Comment: It prevents other websites from easily embedding your images on their site. It presents an obstacle to people that would steal your images. That's all.